# Read Http Request Authorization Header

Tags: javascript, hash, authorization, httprequest

I am dealing with legacy code that runs on a very primitive server. The back-end code of the server can't be touched as its built-in. The main issue here is that I am trying to add an authorization header to my form post, and I don't know how to get that header from the server. But, I have noticed that the browser sends that Authorization header every time it makes a request. Is there a way to intercept that automatic header inserted by the browser and store it in local storage or some like that via javascript?
Example... if I call index.htm from the browser (actual navigation) I do see the authorization header there. However, it is not in the response header.
Thanks

Comment: The `Authorization` header would not be in the response.  That header is intended to be used to pass a token to the backend for authentication.  The response does not need that header.  As far as intercepting the web request, it depends on how it is being constructed, as far as if you are able to proxy some method on the xhr or fetch request to grab the data before letting it continue on.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that is exactly why I am asking the question. I dont have control over server code, and I failed to intercept the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

Check [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData,
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
}).than((response) => {console.log(response.headers); /*your headers*/);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to intercept the request headers not response.

Comment: @alisanad you wont do this at runtime?
Only one way to do this - it create [serviceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API#Service_worker_concepts_and_usage) and add [listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent) to featchEvent